# A record self referencing in mysql

Tags: mysql

I've got a self referencing table in mySql, a table of managers and employees.

```
CREATE TABLE `employee` (
    `employee_id` BIGINT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `firstname` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `lastname` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `manager_id` BIGINT(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`employee_id`),
CONSTRAINT `FK_MANAGER` FOREIGN KEY (`manager_id`) REFERENCES `employee` (`employee_id`)
)
```

I want to know if it's conceptual correct that a record references himself. I explain better: some employees has relationships with some manager, so for example employees 3,5,7 have relationships with manager 1, but I'd like to create a list to show all record related to manager 1 and also manager 1. So I've tried to make manager 1 have relationships with himself, so manager 1 refers to manager 1.

I've got no errors, but wanna know if this is a correct way to implement this relationship or if I will have problems in future.

Thanks

Comment: No. You will not have problems in the future. Referencing a field on the same table is normal to employee manager relation since they are the same person. However, I suggest that you might want to add a `ROLE_ID` field to enforce your constraints and reference them to a `ROLE_TABLE` .

Comment: Thanks! I had already a role_table, I only have a doubt about this situation...

Comment: You can have a `ROLE_ID` field and instead of `MANAGER_ID` you can have `IMMEDIATE_SUPERIOR` then you can form the hierarchy. Just a suggestion.

Comment: Self-referencing tables are common and conceptually correct. You will need to look at db-specific features on how to handle hierarchical data. Oracle has "connect to .. prior". Or CTEs can do the trick now. You will find references in SO to articles like [Managing Hierarichal data in mysql](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/) and [Celko's trees in sql](http://www.ibase.ru/devinfo/DBMSTrees/sqltrees.html)

Comment: I know that self-referencing tables are ok. But the problem here is if record 1 is self referencing to record 1! A record that refers to himself...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion it is not best solution because:

- It limits You to have only 2 levels in management hierarchy(only manager and employee) You can't have manager -> leader -> employee
- You can't easily print a tree of employees
- I practice in bigger company the only person with no one on top would be CEO

Myself I would use this query instead

```
SELECT * FROM employee WHERE employee_id=1
UNION
SELECT * FROM employee WHERE manager_id=1
```

Comment: I will not have this problem. I just want know if a record referencing himself is a wrong solution...

Comment: No, it is not wrong. Just have to be aware of this possibility if You ever going to try get to top of a tree to avoid infinite loop.

Comment: You can have a `ROLE_ID` field and instead of `MANAGER_ID` you can have `IMMEDIATE_SUPERIOR` then you can form the hierarchy.